# How to integrate HTTP testing into my CI

Tags: java, unit-testing, http, integration-testing

I would like to integrate testing my web app with HTTP into my CI system. My original plan was to use a combination of Junit, the Apache HttpClient and a web server I could kick off in Java like Jetty. What have people tried and what has worked?

Btw, I already have unit testing and some integration test that invoke my app's complete spring context. This definitely helps, but at this juncture, I'm interested in using a combination of Http adn Junit code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two "classic" options are:

1. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
2. [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

We have tried both and both work. HTMLUnit may choke on some JavaScript; Selenium requires browser installation and it's a bit tricky to make it run on headless Linux CI server.

I'd say start with HTMLUnit, good if it works for you; otherwise continue to Selenium.